# Make Pepper understanding and speaking German or other none-english languages

Tags: speech-processing, pepper

I am using the "Choreography" software to interact with Pepper. I can create english dialogs there. But I have problems to change the language to (e.g.) German.

In the settings of a Dialog I can choose other languages (e.g. German). **But** when I create a "Topic" there is only a checkbox for English. So I am confused at this point.

:EDIT:

The properties of the project itself does have language settings, too. There you have to check the languages you want to support. Then they are available for the modules.

[image]

Currently I need to restrict my answer to the "Choreography" software only. The software now offers "Topics" in "German". But Pepper now does nothing. There is a problem I currently can not identify.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, buhtz. As it stands, I *think* you're referring to the [robot Pepper](https://www.ald.softbankrobotics.com/en/cool-robots/pepper), though it's not clear. Regardless, questions about how to use or interact with a particular robot or software package should generally be [directed to the vendor](https://www.ald.softbankrobotics.com/en/about-us/contact).

Comment: Questions which can only be answered by the pre-sales or technical support team for a specific manufacturer or supplier aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. *[Practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)* are always welcome here though, so if you edit your question to fit our community guidelines we can reopen it for you. Please take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: @Chuck I checked to how to ask before. You posed only a default textblock to desribte your delete-reason. Could you please again use your own words why you deleted this? I don't understand why.

Comment: I explained in my own words in the [first comment](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/13905/make-pepper-understanding-and-speaking-german-or-other-none-english-languages?noredirect=1#comment22787_13905). You are asking a question that is best and/or only answerable by the software manufacturer. Try [contacting the manufacturer](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/us-en/support). I *do* see that they (sadly) refer people to [Stack Overflow for answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pepper) - [as you appear to already know](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45330210/5171120).

Comment: I closed the question because I think you should contact the vendor. The vendor says go to [so]. The closing message on the comment says, in part, *"Questions which are not specific to robotics are off-topic, but can be asked on other Stack Exchange sites: **Stack Overflow for programming questions**."* Regardless, the template comment says everything: *Questions which can only be answered by the ... technical support team for a specific manufacturer or supplier aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site ... if you edit your question to fit our community guidelines we can reopen it for you.*